# Ho do I create a simple and secure SSO/Authentication Ingestion API for my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, security, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on

**Background**
We have created a web portal which our CUSTOMERS can use to host content for their users. Authentication is done through a login page where a CUSTOMER's user enters their email and address and password. Note: Our CUSTOMERS manages these emails. The portal works really well and serves our CUSTOMERS' needs really well. What they need now is the ability to allow our CUSTOMER to enable SSO from their website to our portal. They already know the email address of the user, as it's their customer or supplier. We are looking for the safest and easiest way to do this.

**Our tech stack**
It's all built on Azure and at the moment we are using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server. Ideally, we would like to stick to this stack but we are open to any other suggestions. The website is SSL encrypted.

**What I was thinking**
Add Azure functions to enable a REST API. Give the CUSTOMER a unique API Key which they can use to request a unique "authenitcation_Key" from our API. The "authentication_key" should expire after 60 minutes and is unique for every CUSTOMER/user combination. When the already authenticated CUSTOMER's user clicks on the link/button to go from the CUSTOMER's website to our portal, the website gets a new "authenitcation_key" and adds it to the HTTP Header for us to consume and validate.

What are the major security concerns/risks to this approach? How can it easily be improved?

Answer (score 0):

The one which you thinking to implement will take lots of time and security tests, why not to use industry proven solutions.

I would suggest you to use IdentityServer4, you easily configure this according to your need. I know you are using .NET full framework, but this will not stop you using IdentityServer4 which uses .NET Core.

Check here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/

Answer (score 0):

If your stack is on Azure, you may just set up an AZURE OpenID Connect server. Your CUSTOMER application can be registered as Openid Connect (or OAuth) client, each request can then send a JWT access_token to your portal, and your portal verify and accept JWT as authentication token.